# Cantidad de veces que un elemento se repite en un array bidimensional

Tags: javascript, array, funciones, bucle-for, objeto

este es mi codigo y me devuelve [1]

```
         function cuantosRepetidos(array, elemento) {
          var contador = 0;

         for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   
        for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
      
        if (array[i] == array[j]) + contador ++ ;
  
         return contador +
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahi no estás recorriendo las dos dimensiones del array, para saber cuántas veces debe hacerse el segundo for deberías hacer array[0].length y en la condición if deberías comparar array[i][j] con elemento en vez de array[i] con array[j]. Deberías cerrar también las llaves correctamente ya que eso seguramente te da problemas y el return se activa en la primera vuelta del bucle, por eso devuelve 1.

```
function cuantosRepetidos(array, elemento) {
                var contador = 0;

                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

                    for (var j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {

                        if (array[i][j] == elemento) + contador++;
                    }
                }
                return contador;
       }
```

siento no haberlo puesto, yo también soy nuevo aquí. En principio esto debería funcionar

Comment: Hola Sergio, gracias por respondet. Podrias escribirmelo, soy muy nuevo en esto de prgramar y logro interpretarte correctamente pero en sintaxis le estoy fallando... gracias de nuevo

Comment: tambien lo intente asi pero me devuelve [const cantidad = array.reduce((array, elemento) => {
        arrayr[elemento] = (elemento[array] || 0) + 1;
        return elemento;
    }, {});
    return cantidad;
}

Comment: Si la verdad que entenderlo sin enseñarlo es complicado siendo nuevo, ha sido fallo mío que soy nuevo en esta página pero ya está corregido creo.

Comment: mil gracias Sergio, ahora si me quedo claro y funciono. Muchismas Gracias y estamos todos aprendiendo, cada uno a su ritmo, intentando poder colaborar entre todos. Saludos

Comment: De nada, toda la razón. Saludos a ti también :)